# How to get 3 stars in Godus voyages?

Tags: android, godus

I'm playing Godus on Android and I've reached *Voyage of Discovery*. There are several missions in that voyage, and the objective is to get 3 stars on all missions.

To receive 3 stars, I must reach a certain score. However, I have no idea how the score is calculated (and the game does not make it clear, that's a design fault).

How is the voyage mission score calculated? How can I get better scores, so that I can get all stars?

Answer (score 1):

Score is given for each follower that reaches the temple, more points for faster completion time.  To get 3 stars in any mission, get all 5 followers as close to a straight-line pathway to the temple as possible.

I've gotten all the rewards on the iPad version, didn't even 1 or 2 2-star levels is fine in the middle levels, because the final levels are worth much more.